issue with edges bevel weight messing up my mesh
i am pretty new to blender (been learning for a couple months) but i am having an issue with the edges bevel weight messing up my mesh. i am watching a video guide for making a car so the modifiers i currently have are the exact same as the guy has, but the issue doesn't happen to him and his mesh looks totally fine.
i thought it was because of the bevel modifier then adding the edges bevel weight but changing/removing it didn't help.
any advice on why this is happening and how i can fix it would be greatly appreciated :)


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/
